# Can't get map to work with highcharts-vue

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I'm making use of the official `highcharts-vue` wrapper for my `vue` project. Following the offical docs, my `main.js` looks like this:

```
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue'
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsNoData from "highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display";
import mapInit from 'highcharts/modules/map'

HighchartsNoData(Highcharts);
mapInit(Highcharts);

Vue.use(HighchartsVue);
```

My chart options are the follwing:

```
let zpSimChart = {
chart: {
        map: 'countries/nl/nl-all-all',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: '#2A3F54',
        formatter: function() {
            return this.point.name;
        },
        style: {
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            fontSize: '10px'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: [{
        allowPointSelect: true,
        data: [{"code":"nl-gr-gm0003","value":3,"name":"Test"},{"code":"nl-gr-gm0005","value":5,"name":"Test2"}],
        name: 'Groei',
        joinBy: ['hc-key', 'code'],
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#7E91AA'
            },
            select: {
                color: '#3B9FF3',
                enabled:true
            }
        },
        color: '#0B62A4',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
        }
    }],
    colorAxis: {
        dataClasses: [{
            to: 9999,
            color: '#0B62A4'
        }]
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    }
};
export { zpSimChart }
```

I left most of the data out (to spare code in this question). I imported the options in my `vue` component and assigned them to `zpSimChart` like so:

```
import { zpSimChart } from "./zpsimchart.js"
    export default {
        name: "zpsim",
        data() {
            return {
                zpSimChart: zpSimChart,
                alertVariant: "",
                alertMsg: "",
                showAlert: false,
                showSpinner: false,
            }
        }
```

Finaly the chart tag looks like this:

```
<highcharts :constructor-type="'mapChart'" :options="zpSimChart"></highcharts>
```

Now, I can see that the chart is recognized (i.e. the zoombuttons for the chart are visible).

I think my problem is, is that I have to specify the actual `javascript` map for the Netherlands somewhere but the offical docs don't state how to do that when using the `highcharts-vue` wrapper. My reference is my old `jQuery` project in which the map did work and where I used to include the actual map in a script tag like this:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/nl/nl-all-all.js"></script>
```

I already tried to include the script tag in my `index.html` like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/icon/favicon.png">
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/nl/nl-all-all.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

But with no luck. Any thoughts on how to get this working?

Comment: I've reproduced your map in jsfiddle and it works correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3v1Lpexn/. However, when I put it into vue app using codesandbox the map is not loading: https://codesandbox.io/s/6lo4n0x40r. I've no idea if there is an issue with the vue code or just codesandbox. Could you check it locally in your app? I mean the way I load map data by importing it in chart component.

Comment: Will take a look at your code tonight!

Comment: @WojciechChmiel I solved it. See my answer at the bottom. thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad the issue is solved;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out that I didn't set the `Highcharts.maps` correctly. I added the following adjustments into my `main.js`:

```
import { mapNetherlands } from "./assets/maps/netherlands"
Highcharts.maps["countries/nl/nl-all-all"] = mapNetherlands;
```

Now my map is displayed correctly.